# Extract URLs from single cell that contains specified domain

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

In excel, each cell in Column A has 1-6 urls in random order separated by ";".

I'm trying to extract urls from each domain, and place them in according columns.

http:/i.stack.imgur.com/J7UJg.jpg (// subbed with / to post)

For example, A2, would have the following,

```
http:/randomwebsite.com/content/mieIEe; 
http:/examplesite.io/jiefaiwjf0293845983725kjsdaf; 
http:/randomwebsite.com/img/fjioewqa; 
https:/www.anotherrandomsite.com/watch=9hDEOjefls; 
http:/www.anotherexample.com/5053/765437/qwreja;
http:/random.com/jfieJOJd344
```

B1 - F1 would each be columns for the different domains.  B1 would be a column for randomwebsite.com, C1 would be for anotherrandomsite.com, .. and so forth.

The results I would want in this case is to have each corresponding url from column A, to show in each designated column.  Like the first url "http:/randomwebsite.com/content/mieIEe" to show in B2, and if same domains come up twice or more, separate them with "," within the same cell as B2 would be "http:/randomwebsite.com/content/mieIE,http:/randomwebsite.com/img/fjioewqa".

I've tried putting the following in B2 and on..

```
=IFERROR(MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2),FIND("; ",$A2)-1),"")
&IFERROR("; "&MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+1),FIND("; ",$A2)-1),"")
```

Does kinda work, but I ran into a problem of determining the actual length of each url.

**Main issues are:**

- some domains are listed twice or more
- not all domains start with http/s www, or end with com

Would there be any standard function methods to solve this within a single cell?

I have no experience with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your post a little longer I realised that you want the URLS in column A to be distributed over the columns B to F and placed in the column having the domain name in its first row (B1:F1). The function you have provided is probably as good as it can be if you restrict yourself to worksheetfunctions.

I have put together a little VBA function that might do the job for you in a slightly different manner:

```
Function furl(urls, dom) ' filter URLs from string urls that belong to domain dom
 Dim uarr, retval$, i%, j%
 retval = ""
 uarr = Split(urls, "; ")
 For i = LBound(uarr) To UBound(uarr)
   If (InStr(uarr(i), dom) > 0) Then retval = retval & "; " & uarr(i)
 Next i
furl = Mid(retval, 3)
End Function
```

First I split the string into its individul urls using your separator "; ". I then run through all the resulting array elements in a for look and check for `dom` to appear there as a substring. If it does i add it to my `retval` string. This string is then returned by assigning it to the function itself (`furl=mid(retval,3)`). The `mid(retval,3)` removes the first two characters of the string.

You should "insert" a "Module" into the VBAproject of your current file and place the above code into that module. In your worksheet you can then use the function just like any other worksheetfunction like in cell `B2`:

```
=furl($a2,b$1)
```

In the column headers `B1:F1` you should enter the *minimum version* of your URLs like `'randomwebsite.com'`, leaving out all optional stuff like `'http://'` and `'www.'`.

**UPDATE**

Yes, pnuts has a point with his comment!

I updated my function. Now it checks for possible word boundaries (any of the characters in `"./"`) before and `"/?#"` after the given domain name:

```
Function furl(urls, dom) ' filter URLs from string urls that belong to domain dom
 Dim uarr, retval$, i%, j%, lft$, ldom%
 retval = ""
 ldom = Len(dom)
 uarr = Split(urls, "; ")
 For i = LBound(uarr) To UBound(uarr)
   j = InStr(uarr(i), dom)
   If (j > 0) Then
     ' "word boundary"-char before the found position:
     If (j = 1) Then lft = "." Else lft = Mid(uarr(i), j - 1, 1)
     '   right boundary                                  left boundary 
     If (InStr("/?#", Mid(uarr(i), j + ldom, 1)) > 0 And InStr("./", lft)) Then
       retval = retval & "; " & uarr(i)
     End If
   End If
 Next i
 furl = Mid(retval, 3)
End Function
```

I tested it and it works. Now I hope I can convince my downvoters to have mercy with me again ;-)

**OR** maybe, explain *why* they downvoted ...

**OR** maybe, even come up with a better solution - that would help us all!

Comment: I don't quite understand the language yet, but the updated version worked like a charm.  I should use the opportunity to learn VBA.  Thanks much!